# Installing JDK without administrator privileges

Tags: java, installation, limited-user

I am trying to install JDK at office laptop but it says I need administrator privileges. I have only access to my own account at work.

How can I install the Java Development Kit without administrator rights?

Comment: your office probably has some sort of elevated privileges so you can install software, ask you manager or sys admin

Comment: Believe me, sometimes it is not as simple... In my previous company I had to fill a form to justify my needs and then wait one month...

Comment: Yes, actually I have to fill out bunch of forms online. But I don't have access to the online website from home. I have to install it tonight though.

Comment: There is [an identical question over on Super User](http://superuser.com/questions/333647/how-can-i-install-the-java-development-kit-jdk-on-a-windows-machine-if-i-dont). Please see that question and its answers.  I believe that my recent late answer there might solve your problem.  But first please see [Joe Taylor's comment on the question](http://superuser.com/questions/333647/how-can-i-install-the-java-development-kit-jdk-on-a-windows-machine-if-i-dont#comment1199815_333647).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Here is a workaround to install java without admin privileges or without administrator password. For this you need cygwin installed which does not require admin privileges.
In the utils make sure you select cabextract.exe to install it.

Fireup cygwin bash shell.

Type cabextract jdk1.6.exe  <-- jdk file name

this will extract all the files into the current directory.

Move tools.zip to a new directory and unzip it using cygwin or windows explorer. This will be your java directory.

Hint: Try to subsitite 7zip instead of cabextract and cygwin. If it works it will be much faster.

Edit: This doesn't get you a working JDK with the latest versions of jdk 6 and 7. Many of the jar files (eg rt.jar) are compressed so they need to be decompressed using unpack200.

Just go through each directory looking for files with a .pack extension and unpack them using unpack200, eg: .\jre\bin\unpack200 .\jre\lib\rt.pack .\jre\lib\rt.jar

This allows you to run java programs however I still had trouble with Eclipse as there was some issue with annotations, so there's probably another step that is missing.

In the answers to [this similar question on Superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/333647/how-to-install-java-on-a-windows-machine-without-having-admin-right) is available a script that automatically finds all .pack files and unpacks them in the right folders.

Comment: 7zip only partially extracted the cab file. It got jre.msi (which it was also able to extract) but not the jdk part of the cab file.

Comment: If you have cygwin, to find the .pack files `$ find . -name *.pack`

Comment: This didn't work for me with JDK7u71 on Windows 7.  But the answer below about 'Server JRE' did work.

Answer (score 54):

Starting with Java SE 7u21, Oracle offers a so-called *Server JRE* for download. This is a standard .tar.gz archive that you can extract anywhere on your computer. Although the download is called *JRE*, it contains a "normal" JDK subdirectory (including the javac compiler etc.).

Instructions:

- download the "Server JRE" from [Java download site](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html)
- extract the .tar.gz
- add the *bin* subdirectory to your PATH

Comment: The JRE != The JDK; it's lacking a compiler, etc.

Comment: @pioto Did you actually check the download? It's a complete JDK.

Comment: I stand corrected: this does contain a javac binary, it seems, despite being a full 100MB lighter than the JDK. I haven't verified if it all functions as intended or not, though.

Comment: Unfortunately the Server JRE is not available for Mac.

Comment: great. although it is missing 32-bit windows version. which isn't surprising for "server" version, but sometimes still needed for a desktop pc.

Comment: The JDK is not complete. JAVAFX is absent, as an example!

Comment: As already mentionned, it works on windows, it has a compiler, but has no jFXWebkit.dll, no sources.zip, and may not work for ui (since it is intended for server only). Still a nice workaround.

Comment: Well, adding to the PATH imposes a problem if you don't have Admin rights... :/

Comment: @Zordid Why? On Windows, you can edit the environment variables for your user account (instead of the system-wide ones) without Admin privileges, and on Linux/Unix, you can just set your $PATH variable accordingly (e.g. in your .bashrc)

Comment: Doesn't work for me. The package contains a directory called jdk, but my IDE (IntelliJ) doesn't accept it as a JDK folder.

Answer (score 31):

Oracle changed the package format in **update 102** as pointed by [**@Webrjn**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/503025/weberjn) on a previous answer at this question, but the unpack method still works with two more unzip actions:

[image]

1. The installation executable of the JDK is a zipped file, so just unzip it with 7z to any folder you want.
2. Go to the directory  **`.rsrc/1033/JAVA_CAB10/`**.
3. The only file there is **`111`**, which is also a zipped file containing tools.zip. Unzip it to get **`tools.zip`**.
4. So now perform the original unpack process, by unzipping **`tools.zip`** to your desired java installation path.
5. Open a windows command prompt and run:

   ```
   for /r %i in (*.pack) do .\bin\unpack200.exe -r -v %i %~pi%~ni.jar
   ```

   The **`unpack200`** program complains about garbage at the end of the files, but the unpacked jars are tested ok by 7z.
6. Java source **`src.zip`** is within the file **`110`** located inside **`.rsrc/1033/JAVA_CAB9`**.

By the way, update 101 only contains the tools.zip file and can be installed with the previous unpack method.

Comment: "Java source src.zip is the file `110` at `.rsrc/1033/JAVA_CAB9`": that gives me (with 8u102) a `javafx-src.zip` of only 5 MB, as opposed to a regular `src.zip` found in `jdk-8u102-linux-x64.tar.gz` (21 MB)

Comment: You are talking about different files, javafx-src.zip is the source for JavaFx only classes while src.zip is the source for Java classes. javafx-src.zip size is 4972 KB.

Comment: I agree. My point was: I am only interested in `src.zip`, and I don't think `src.zip` is present in one of those CAB files. I always have to extract it from the Linux package.

Comment: In Windows .exe, it is present at **.rsrc\1033\JAVA_CAB9\110**, while in Linux tgz it is at the root. Just unzip file **110**

Comment: That is what I did (unzip 110) and... it gave me `javafx-src.zip`, not `src.zip`

Comment: Sorry, I coundn´t reproduce it. I just downloaded **jdk-8u102-windows-x64.exe** from Oracle.com, unziped **.rsrc\1033\JAVA_CAB9\110** as discussed above and got **src.zip** with a size of 20755 KB.

Comment: Since this is the most current and correct work-around, this should be stickied to the top even if it's not the selected answer according to OP.

Comment: Has saved my dinosaur-driven, process-lacking workspace several times already... Thank you, man

Comment: Note that step 5 as it is currently written will fail if you have spaces in your path to the tools folder.

Answer (score 15):

Here are all the steps that got the JDK installed on Windows 7 without admin rights.

1. You need the `cabextract` program to extract the installer files. I tried 7zip but it didn't extract the cab properly. Instead, I used cygwin. You can get the `setup.exe` program from their website, but you must rename it because Windows assumes that anything called "setup" requires admin rights. I renamed it to `cygwin.exe`. Run that. It'll ask you where to install. I chose the `cygwin` directory in my home directory. When the pop-up asks you which programs to install, type "cabinstall" in the search bar. Expand the "Archive" section and make sure the "cabinstall" is not set to "skip". (Click the "skip" text until the highest number shows.) Proceed with install. This takes a few minutes.
2. Optional: Add `cygwin\bin` to your path. Do this from control panel, user accounts, change my environment variables, edit PATH.
3. Download the JDK. I downloaded jdk-6u45-windows-x64.exe.
4. In the directory where that file is: `mkdir tmp`
5. `cd tmp`
6. `cabextract ..\jdk-6u45-windows-x64.exe`
7. Make a new directory for the actual JDK. I used `jdk` in my home directory.
8. Extract the `tools.zip` file into that. It comes with the Java runtime, so you don't need the other files in the original cab, such as `jre.msi`.
9. Unpack all the `.pack` files. You can do that manually by running the `bin/unpack200` program on them, or use bash (if you installed cygwin above):

   1. `bash`
   2. `for f in $(../cygwin/bin/find . -name "*.pack"); do bin/unpack200 $f ${f%.*}.jar; done`
10. Add `jdk/bin` to your PATH (see step 2 above).

Comment: Note: You may have to run the cygwin setup program with the -B option if you do not have admin rights.

Answer (score 6):

1. Download the JDK
2. Extract it by using 7 ZIP (Extract the exe file)
   [image]

It contains a single file tools.zip, which contains all the files we need.
Extract the tools.zip to the desired JDK directory (e.g. “D:\JavaJDK\”).
3. Unpack

Now we need to unpack a few files packed with pack200. We do that by executing this script in a console windows inside the JDK directory (e.g. “D:\JavaJDK\”):

```
for /R %f in (.\*.pack) do @"%cd%\bin\unpack200" -r -v -l "" "%f" "%~pf%~nf.jar"
```

Regard that you will have to adjust the path of the unpack200 binary (“D:\JavaJDK\bin\unpack200”) to your chosen directory.

4. Congrats you now have a working, portable JDK!
   [image]

Reference: [this link](https://www.whitebyte.info/programming/java/how-to-install-a-portable-jdk-in-windows-without-admin-rights)

Comment: Thank you, the only working way without installing external program.

Comment: Nevertheless, this method lacks `src.zip` so I had to follow [Leonardo Vidal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38511724/535203) to get this file and have a full JDK.

Answer (score 4):

I guess you are on Windows.
You cannot install the JDK provided by Oracle without administrator right. What you can do is installing it on an other machine (or find a machine where it is installed) and copy the jdk dir.

Comment: Yes it is Windows. Okay so I will install it in another machine and then try transferring it to office laptop. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

jdk-8u102-windows-x64.exe no longer works with the unpack method, Oracle seem to have changed the package format.

[image]

Comment: This answers my question, I was wondering how all the other answers did it

Answer (score 2):

If you can install it on any other machine then this solution will help you.

- Install it on another machine.
- Bring the jdk folder on your machine and set system and classpath variable to the path where you have copied the jdk folder. You should be able to run your programs.

Comment: 'Rohan Durve' has mentioned one alternate, if you don't have any other machine, install it in USB and later copy it in your system.

Comment: Hmms so you are saying I transfer it through USB from another laptop to office laptop. Will that work? I ll try it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a good alternative is to use OpenJDK, [here](https://github.com/alexkasko/openjdk-unofficial-builds) is an unnoficial build for windows, so you can download the Zip file extract to any folder and set the JAVA_HOME for your windows user. I ran Android Studio this way.

Answer (score 2):

In order to easily install Java JDK on Windows **without administrator privileges**, you can use https://aws.amazon.com/corretto/. It contains a portable `amazon-corretto-<version>-windows-x64-jdk.zip` file, that you just need to download and unzip.

1. Download the portable zip file from amazon.com, e.g. https://d3pxv6yz143wms.cloudfront.net/8.232.09.1/amazon-corretto-8.232.09.1-windows-x64-jdk.zip
2. Unzip it in a folder, e.g. `C:\Users\John\programs`
3. Set the JAVA_HOME variable, e.g. `set JAVA_HOME=C:\Users\John\programs\jdk1.8.0_232`
4. Add the path to the "bin" folder to the PATH: e.g. `set PATH = %PATH%; %JAVA_HOME%\bin`
5. Test if the installation works with `javac -version`

***Remark #1.*** I am proposing this alternative technique using Amazon Corretto because other proposed answers requires 7-zip for which you need administrative rights to install, and I did not find a simple portable .zip version of 7-zip.

***Remark #2.*** You can set up your environment by having a `my-cmd.cmd` file which contains the needed variables:

```
rem # PROMPT is an optional question of taste ;-)
prompt [$P]$_$$$S
rem # VARIABLE(S)
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Users\UW31RY\programs\jdk1.8.0_232
rem # PATH
set PATH=C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\system32;%JAVA_HOME%\bin
rem # Clear the screen!
cls
```

and creating a shortcut with `%windir%\system32\cmd.exe /K "my-cmd.cmd"` as `Target:` value, and the folder which contains the `my-cmd.cmd` file as `Start in:` value, e.g. `C:\Users\John\work`.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.ehow.com/how_6012601_install-java-admin-privileges.html

Here you go man, Good luck. This worked for me.

## Instructions on above link

1
Insert your portable USB drive into your home computer's USB slot.

2
On your home computer, navigate to the "Download Java JDK" link in the resources section.

3
Click the red "Download" button. When asked to log-in, click "Skip this step." Click "Save file" to download the file to your computer.

4
Double-click the ".exe" file you downloaded to begin the installation wizard for Java SE 6. Click "Accept" to the License Agreement.

5
On the Custom Setup page, click the small hard-drive buttons next to "Source Code," "Public JRE," and "Java DB" and for each select "Don't install this feature now."

6
Click the "Change..." button on the bottom right corner, then from the drop down menu, under "Look in:" select your portable usb drive. Click "Create New Folder" button in the in the top right corner (the folder icon), and name the new folder "JDK". Select the JDK folder and click "OK."

7
Click "Next" and wait while Java installs.

8
Open Notepad by going to "Start," "Programs," "Accessories" "Notepad."

9
In Notepad, copy-paste the following two-line batch script:
set Path=%~d0\JDK\bin;%PATH%
cmd

10
Click "File," "Save as," navigate to your USB drive root directory, and type "RunMeForJava.bat" as the name of your file and click "Save."

11
Insert your USB drive into the computer where you do not have Administrator privileges and double-click the ".bat" file in your USB root directory. A Command Prompt window will open. Type "javac" (without the quotes) to see that Java works and is fully installed.

Answer (score 1):

The method presented by [Lawrence](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17161610/773874) works but you can also use `7-zip` and [`git bash`](http://git-scm.com/) to do the whole thing without much trouble.

NOTE: `git bash` comes with some gnu utils and `unpack200` is one of them.

There is another small thing to do though. The `src.zip` file which comes with `JDK` is not present after the unpacking so to do that you can download the Linux `tar.gz` version and unpack it twice with `7-zip` and then copy the missing `src.zip` file to the windows unpacked `JDK`.

Not having the `src.zip` is not a big deal but it will provide you easy access to some JDK sources in tools like `Intellij IDEA`.

Answer (score 0):

Nice work by @Lawrence by using Cygwin. 
Let me show you similar steps without using any external tools.

**Installing using utilities at the system without admin rights:**

This works on Windows 7 or later on a system without admin rights

1. Download the latest version of JDK: You can find it here http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html
2. Use 7zip tool to extract the executable into a directory. Again extract the inside `tools.zip` file within.
3. Goto `..\jre\bin` Use `SHIFT` and `Right Click` and open `Command Prompt`.
4. Type `unpack200 SRC DST`. Inplace of SRC: Search `*.pack` files within the extracted directory, copy paste the directory location of `.pack` files, Inplace of DST: Use the same path of `.pack` files, and replace the filename with `.jar`
5. Do this for all the `.pack` files available in the directory. (Some 6-8 files are there for JDK8u65)
6. Launch Eclipse, choose a project, click `Alt+Enter`, click on `Build Path`
7. Goto `Libraries`, remove available system JRE if any. Click on `Add Library`, choose `JRE System Library` then `NEXT`, Click `Alternate JRE` , click on `Installed JREs`. Click `Add`, `Standard VM` then `NEXT`, choose `Directory`.
8. Now choose the directory location of the extracted JDK you performed in step 2, then click `FINISH`, `APPLY` then `OK`

You must be good to go to run the project without actually installing JDK.
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I have tried several ways of installation, but there is a common problem:

In the worst case, **if any installation requires admin privilege, then you will not be able to use 7zip because there is no portable version of 7zip.** But, in Windows 10 and later versions of Windows 7(if my memory serves me well), **extracting zip file is possible without any program installation**: just open the `.zip` file with "Windows explorer" and extract them. However, this only works a normal zip file, not with JDK installer.

So, I have tried another way and it works(for oracle jdk 1.8-191): **you can install a JDK in other PC where you have privilege, pass it to your company PC, and set it as the JDK to use**.

1. just intall the JDK in another PC where you have admin privilege, such as that you have at home
2. Zip that `JAVA_HOME` folder(the parent folder of `bin`), copy it to a USB driver, and take that to your company.
3. Unzip in a folder where you have full access, like `C:\Users\<your_name>\java`(because some company also restrict pasting into `Program Files` or somewhere else, but will never restrict what you do in your personal user folder
4. Set `JAVA_HOME` variable to there(if you are not allowed to do that, just skip). The same applies to setting up the `java` path(adding `bin\java` to PATH variable)
5. Open Intellij IDEA or Eclipse, setup your new JDK in the IDE to point to there.
6. Write a simple Hello World program to verify.

I found this because when I look into the JDK installer, I see very similar structure as in JDK folder. So I suspect the installation only consists of extracting the content into a foler, plus some config, which we can do manually. Looks like that my theory is proved.