# How to change JDK installation directory in Windows XP?

Tags: java

Every time I start the `jdk-6u39-windows-i586.exe` I get this error:

> This account does not have sufficient privileges to install Java(TM). Please login to an account with administrative permissions.

This happens immediately, before the wizard appears.

I think this is because the exe file is trying to install to `C:\Program Files`, but install anything to `C:\Program Files` is restricted to admins. So I am trying to install to `C:\opt`. However the JDK doesn't provide me option to change the installation path.

Comment: I'm sure it does. Don't you see a "custom" option during installation?

Comment: I don't get the chance to see any option. What I experienced is this: "Double click on .exe" -> see the error.

Comment: Please contact Java installer support (aka the vendor) for your support options. Tell them the issue you have. Find out if a solution exists. Document the solution with your question then either as answer if that solves your issue -or- inside your question telling what you tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

Run from command prompt, `jdk-6u39-windows-i586.exe /s /INSTALLDIRPUBJRE=C:\opt\`

Referenced from: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/install/windows/jdk-installation-windows.html#Run

Comment: That changes where the public JRE included with the JDK is installed, but does it change where the **JDK** is installed?

Comment: Did you try that? In my experiences the JDK includes the JRE. Are you able to try it? If not, I can give it a shot

Comment: I tried this, but this time I don't see anything show up. `
C:\Documents and Settings\aa\My Documents\Downloads>jdk-6u39-windows-i586.exe /s /INSTALLDIRPUBJRE=C:\opt\jdk1.6.0_39\

C:\Documents and Settings\aa\My Documents\Downloads>` I created that jdk1.6.0_39 folder inside `C:\opt\` just fyi.

Comment: The `\s` tag prompts the installer to run silently. Try running without that tag - you might still have an error with permissions.

Comment: Yep, i see the same error again as expected.

Comment: I am receiving an error that I already have the program installed. My resources have been tapped, I suggest finding an Admin to install the environment.

Comment: By the way - here is an interesting approach:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10891405/installing-jdk-administrator-privileges

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work. Thanks for the help anyway. I guess I'll just ask the admin people