# Install Java 8 without Admin Rights

Tags: java, admin-rights

How to install Java JDK 8 in windows?

Do I require admin right?

What Happens if i just copy JDK from one system to another with admin rights.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Steps To Do that:

STEP1 : Install JAVA JDK 8 in personal system where you have admin rights.

STEP2 : Copy the install JDK folder to system where you dont have admin rights.

STEP3: Go to Start Menu and Search environment and click on "Edit environment variable for your account"

[image]

STEP4: Now Click on Add in User Variables and add below local environment variables.

A. JAVA_HOME

[image]

B. PATH

[image]

C. CLASSPATH

[image]

It works absolutely fine. I have been using JDK like this for almost a year.

I found similar post but it has different technique.
[Installing JDK without administrator privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10891405/installing-jdk-without-administrator-privileges)

Comment: Although this still requires admin privileges on another system...

Comment: The installation package from Oracle does not give the option to pick a location.